# Manipulating DOM data without affecting the view

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>

<p id="intro">Hello <em id="abcd">intro</em> World!</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var txt=document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML;
var el = document.createElement("span");
el.innerHTML = txt;
var aa = el.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML;
alert( aa );
</script>
</body></html>
```

The above is a simple snippet. Actually I have an HTML editor and when the user saves the data I should save only the required content. Here I am getting the content of an element and manipulating it with DOM and pass the details to the server. This way I will not change the page content (user view remains the same) and he/she will continue editing the document.

The above is a simple example but in the real case I have to remove, change and move certain elements. The above code fails `el.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML`. Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Why don't you just add the element to the document but use style `display: none` then you can manipulate it and then remove it

Comment: Ah ok I see why you don't want to add it to the page, because the id's would clash with the existing. Ignore my first comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a hidden iframe to manipulate all your changes, thus creating a separate DOM, then simply pull back the results you want.

```
var iframe;
if (document.createElement && (iframe = document.createElement('iframe'))) {
    iframe.name = iframe.id = "externalDocument";
    iframe.className = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    var externalDocument;
    if (iframe.contentDocument) {
        externalDocument = iframe.contentDocument;
    } else if (iframe.contentWindow) {
        externalDocument = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    }
    else if (window.frames[iframe.name]) {
        externalDocument = window.frames[iframe.name].document;
    }

    if (externalDocument) {
        externalDocument.open();
        externalDocument.write('<html><body><\/body><\/html>');
        externalDocument.close();

        /* Run your manipulations here */
        var txt = document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML;
        var el = document.createElement("span");
        el.innerHTML = txt;

        /* Attach your objects to the externalDocument */
        externalDocument.body.appendChild(el);

        /* Reference the externalDocument to manipulate */
        var aa = externalDocument.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML;
        alert(aa);
    }

    /* Completed manipulation - Remove iFrame */
    document.removeChild(iframe);
}
```

I have it working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ucpvP/

Comment: I have to try this concept. Also I need to remove this iframe everytime. Hope this works in all browsers.

Comment: I have added code at the end to remove the iframe afterwards. It should work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery like given below.

```
  function SaveData() //Your add function
    {
       var txt=$("#intro").html();
       $(document).append("<span id='abcd'>" + txt+ "</span>");
       var aa = $("#abcd").hmtl();
       alert(aa);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DOM Element that is never appended to the DOM. 
I use this 'cleanup' function:

```
  function cleanup(str){
    var tester = document.createElement('div'),
        invalid, result;
    tester.innerHTML = str;

    //elements I don't allow
    invalid = tester.querySelectorAll('script,object,iframe,style,hr,canvas');

    // the cleanup (remove unwanted elements)
    for (var i=0;i<invalid.length;(i+=1)){
      invalid[i].parentNode.removeChild(invalid[i]);
    }

    result = tester.innerHTML;
    tester = invalid = null;

    //diacritics to html-encoded
    return result.replace(/[\u0080-\u024F]/g,
                          function(a) {return '&#'+a.charCodeAt(0)+';';}
                         )
                 .replace(/%/g,'%25');
  }
  //usage:
  cleanup(document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML);
```

You can extend the function with your own code to remove, change and move certain elements.